# Regex: Allow a string that contains "foo" but not if that same string also contains "bar"

Tags: python, regex

My input is a filename, some examples:

```
/some/file/path/thefooisgood.txt
/some/file/path/thisfooisalsogood.txt
/some/file/path/thisfooalsohasbar.txt
```

I want to find/allow all filenames/paths that contain the substring `foo` so long as the string doesn't *also* have the substring `bar` in it.

Substring `bar` may appear anywhere in the file path, doesn't always necessarily come after `foo` and may sometimes be in the path name, not just the filename. Same goes for `foo`. I can't seem to get it right.

Comment: You may use: `^(?!.*bar).*foo` or check this demo: https://regex101.com/r/tRl9Je/1

Comment: C#? Perl? JavaScript?

Comment: Sorry I forgot to mention that. I am using python. I'm testing anubhava's response in my full project. So far it looks like it solves my problem!

Comment: @anubhava if you write your solution as an answer I can mark it as good. :thumbsup: Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may use a negative lookahead based regex as this:

```
^(?!.*bar).*foo
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tRl9Je/1)

**Details:**

- `(?!.*bar)`: Assert that we don't have `bar` anywhere in input
- `.*foo`: Match `foo` anywhere in input